# get only visible elements inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, reactjs, readiumjs

Lets say that I have an iframe that renders some html that I provide. The iframe has a fixed height. It renders what it can inside it's height and shows scrollbar for the rest.

My question is, how can I fetch the html contents of the iframe that are visible in the viewport using javascript.

I only want to get the contents that are visible, not the ones that are hidden under the scroll.

[image]

i.e. I only want to fetch the marked contents as a javascript document
[image]

Comment: Do you want to change the height of the iframe to match the contents of what it is displaying, and as a result removing the scroll bar? Or do you just want to remove the scroll bar, and as a result have content that doesn't fit?

Comment: @3limin4t0r I've updated my question to be more clear. I actually want to get the text contents inside the iframe. but I only want to get the contents that are currently visible on screen.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `scrolling="no"`?

```
<iframe scrolling="no" src="http://www.google.com" width="400px" height="300"></iframe>
```

Comment: I've updated my question to be more clear. I actually want to get the text contents inside the iframe. but I only want to get the contents that are currently visible on screen.